# Access upper class property for List<T> in T class C#

Tags: c#, class, properties, parent

There are my classes:

```
public class myClass1
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public List<myItem> Items { get; set; }
}
public class myClass2
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public List<myItem> Items { get; set; }
}
public class myItem
{
    private void MyMethod()
    {
        int ParentClass_CodeProperty = ???
    }
}
```

How to access (Code property) in upper (or Parent) class ?

example :

```
string ParentClass_CodeProperty = this.Parent.GetType().GetProperty("Code").GetValue(a, null).ToString()
```

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag.

Comment: relevant language is C#

Comment: There is no parent/child (inheritance) relationship here. One class just contains a collection of another. If I create a List<string> in one of my classes, there is no way for the `String` class to know anything about my class.

Comment: Is this just hypothetical? Do you have a specific problem that you're trying to solve through inheritance?

Comment: Do you *want* to use reflection because you can't change the classes to create a relationship between them, or is that just a last resort attempt you were making?

Comment: This doesn't even compile... what is `item` in the `List<>` in `myClass1`? Did you mean `myItem`? Please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: so a ListViewItem how find the ListView ? (for example)

Comment: "so a ListViewItem how find the ListView ?" You either *start* from the ListView or you have a ListView property in ListViewItem.

Comment: List View contain a (List<ListViewItem>) property

Comment: I'm sorry bassfader. Code Edited now. yes item is myItem

Comment: A list view contains an [Items Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a `ListViewItemCollection`. When an item is added to this collection, the `Add` method calls an internal method on the `ListViewItem` that sets the `ListView` property of the `ListViewItem`. This way, the item knows about it's parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is modify your `MyItem` class to have a `ParentClassCode` property, and let this get set through the constructor:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public int ParentClassCode { get; set; }

    public MyItem(int parentClassCode)
    {
        ParentClassCode = parentClassCode;
    }
    private void MyMethod()
    {
        // Now we can refer to ParentClassCode
    }
}
```

Then you would set the parent class code on creation of a new `MyItem`:

```
MyClass1 class1 = new MyClass1();
class1.Code = 42;
class1.Items.Add(new MyItem(class1.Code));
```

Another way to do this, without using the constructor, would be to create a method on the containing class that should be used to add items to the list, and in that `AddItem` method, set the property:

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public List<MyItem> Items { get; set; }

    public void AddItem(MyItem item)
    {
        if (item == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        item.ParentClassCode = Code;
        Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Of course this means there's more work to do to prevent users from bypassing your `AddItem` method and calling `MyClass1.Items.Add(item);`, but you get the idea.

Comment: Sure, that is just one way to do it (an easy way). I added a second example that might be helpful.

Comment: good. have you other solution without Contractor and AddItem method ? please see again my codes

Comment: Not that I can think of. What don't you like about the constructor/additem method that you want to do differently?

Comment: I'm using constructor now. AddItem() method is not good. because users can use Items.Add() and Code will be Null

Comment: Yes, you would have to make the list private and expose your own methods to access the items. Like implementing ICollection would probably work well

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions.

First solution is to pass dependency inside your constructor, from the start of class lifetime, just like every IoC framework do:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    int Code {get;}
}
public class myClass1 : IMyClass
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public List<myItem> Items { get; set; }
}
public class myClass2 : IMyClass
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public List<myItem> Items { get; set; }
}
public class myItem
{
    //Initialization scope
    private readonly int _parentCode;
    public myItem(IMyClass parent)
    {
       _parentCode = parent.Code;
    }

    //...

    //Execution scope
    private void MyMethod()
    {
        int ParentClass_CodeProperty = _parentCode;
    }
}
```

Second solution is to delegate dependency injection to outer scope and pass it when it actualy needed:

```
public class myItem
{
    private void MyMethod(IMyClass parent)
    {
        int ParentClass_CodeProperty = parent.Code;
    }
}

//...

//Initialization scope
var _myItemToParentIndex = new Dictionary<myItem, IMyClass>();

var item = new myItem();
var cl = new myClass2();
myClass2.Items.Add(item);
_myItemToParentIndex.Add(item, myClass2);

//...

//Execution scope
item.MyMethod(_myItemToParentIndex[item]);
```

Other solutions is pretty much more or less similar, like overloading *IMyClass* with custom *AddItem*, *RemoveItem* methods and so on. They just represent how early your dependency will be injected in *myItem* class.